# Combobox always visible from all pages of the ASP.NET Core 7.0 razor pages application (no MVC)

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

How can I make a combobox always visible from all pages of the ASP.NET Core 7.0 Razor pages application?

I tried to insert a form with the combobox in the `_Layout.cshtml` file but I can't populate it or manage the submit.

Is there anyone who can give me directions?

Thank you.

Comment: Using the _layout.cshtml file it's correct. Why can't you populate it? You need to show us some code

Comment: the combobox contains the connection strings to the databases and should be displayed on all pages of the application so that you can change databases at any time. So I thought about inserting the combobox into a form in the _Layout file but I don't understand how to populate and manage it.

Comment: Where should the values come from? If it’s a registered service, for example, you can inject it directly into the razor layout using the `@inject` directive.

Comment: Hi @steve fax, could you pls share enough code to reproduce your issue?

Comment: You can use a partial view for the combobox and include it in the layout file.

Comment: do you kindly have an example to show me?